# In C#, how can i get a key-value pair of query strings where key should be the attribute and value should be what variable is associated with $ symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

The query string is of type:

```
filter[dummyId1]=like:$Id1&filter[dummyId2]=like:$Id2
```

What I need is:

```
key:dummyId1, Value:Id1
Key:dummyId2, Value:Id2
```

How can I do this?
I have tried using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` and `String.Split("&")`, but
neither give the desired results.

Comment: A little bit more information will be nice. What have you tried to accomplish this. Any code snippets? Have you tried/heared of Regex or sth.?

Comment: Put extra information on the question in the question body, not in the comments.

Comment: @Martin regex will be too complicated for that and can extract just $ associated variable name. I need key as well.

Comment: It seems like you're skipping some of the important information in the query string. That is, `filter[dummyId2]=like:$Id2` not only tells you `dummyId2` filters for `$Id2`, but also that it should use a `like` match rather than an equality match (or startswith, endswith, greater than, less than, etc).

Comment: @VikasSaraf Just as an option I posted a possible Regex as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

How are you reading the `query params`?

Ok, coded some examples

- Automagically from `[FromQuery]`
- Iterate over `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`
- `NamedValueCollection` Linq mapped to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` using regex provided by @Martin

```
[HttpGet("kvp")]
public ActionResult GetKvp([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> filter)
{
    // This line will print {"dummyId1":"like:$Id1","dummyId2":"like:$Id2"}
    System.Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(filter)); //automagica fromquery

    var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());

    foreach (string item in parsed)
    {
      // this will print filter[dummyId1] / filter[dummyId2]
      System.Console.WriteLine(item);
      // this will print like:$Id1 / like:Id2
      System.Console.WriteLine(parsed.Get(item));
     }

      var kvps = parsed.AllKeys.Select(x =>
      {
        // Regex from @Martin answer
        var key = Regex.Match(x, "filter\\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]");
        var filterName = key.Groups[1].Value;
        var value = parsed.Get(x);
        var newValue = value.Replace("like:$", "", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(filterName, newValue);
      }).ToList();

      // this will print [{"Key":"dummyId1","Value":"Id1"},{"Key":"dummyId2","Value":"Id2"}]
      System.Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(kvps));

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Full and more "aspnetcoreish" example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:

```
/filter\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]=([a-z]+):([\$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g
```

[image]

If you need more supported values you can add your options in the brakets f.e.:
`[a-z]+` change to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to support not just `a-z`. To test your queries you can use: regex101.com which helps a lot.

[Here is a small example for you query string](https://regex101.com/r/OYIQVh/1)